# How do I create a new controller and route in Refinerycms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailchimp, refinerycms, gibbon

I am trying to hook up Refinerycms with mailchimp.  I am aware that there is an engine available at (https://github.com/Wirelab/refinerycms-mailchimp) however, it does not seem to be compatible with refineycms 2.1.2. So I have decided use the Gibbon gem API wrapper.

Also, I read about decorators in the manual and that seems to be useful when you want to modify an existing Controller or Model.

How should I create a new controller?

Should I:

1. generate a new engine 
    rails generate refinery:engine  subscriber email:string
    This seems like an overkill to generate an engine to only add a controller and a route. I don't want to store the subscribers email on the database when I can have access to them on mailchimp.com
2. add another subscribe action to PostsController.
   I don't feel good about doing this because subscribers seems to be a resource and therefore deserves a controller.
3. create a new controller by simply running: [  rails generate controller subscribers index subscribe ]
   I feel this can potentially cause a problem when updating to a newer version of Refinerycms.

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: I turned over the project to someone else.